# Assign items evenly to dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-itertools

I've got a list and a list of dictionaries and I want to assign items from the list to one of two keys in the dictionaries. Both keys in the dictionaries must have values assigned, no item should appear more than once in each dictionary, and the distribution of each item should be balanced.

I'm going to use fruit:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'papaya', 'kiwi']
baskets = [{'basket': 'one', 'fruit1': '', 'fruit2': ''},
           {'basket': 'two', 'fruit1': '', 'fruit2': ''},
           {'basket': 'three', 'fruit1': '', 'fruit2': ''},
           {'basket': 'four', 'fruit1': '', 'fruit2': ''}]
```

The number of baskets shouldn't matter.

This is how I'm doing it at the moment:

```
import itertools

def in_basket(frt, bskt):
    if frt in bskt.values():
        return True
    else:
        return False

g = itertools.cycle(fruits)
fruit = next(g)

for basket in baskets:
    basket['fruit1'] = fruit
        fruit = next(g)

for basket in baskets:
    while True:
        if not in_basket(fruit, basket):
           basket['fruit2'] = fruit
           break
        else:
           fruit = next(g)
```

The problem with this approach is that I get an imbalance with the distribution of fruits.  There could be a lot more baskets.

Is there a way to achieve a uniform distribution of fruits in each basket slot?

**Edit** - the output is the updated 'baskets' list, with all the fruit slots filled.

Comment: What is the required result (sample list) for the lists you mentioned?

Comment: Yes I know I'm being lazy, but could you give an example of how your output should look?

Comment: The output is simply the updated 'baskets' list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a simple round robin:

```
g = itertools.cycle(fruits)
for basket in baskets:
    basket['fruit1'] = next(g)
    basket['fruit2'] = next(g)
```

The distribution is balanced *by design*. The only caveat is that once you know what is fruit1 in one basket, fruit2 is automatically determined. If you do not like it, you can use next fruit for each possible fruit:

```
g = itertools.cycle(fruits)
fruit_iter = {}
for i, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
    fruit_iter[fruit] = itertools.cycle(fruits[i+1:] + fruits[:i])
for basket in baskets:
    fruit = next(g)
    basket['fruit1'] = fruit
    basket['fruit2'] = next(fruit_iter[fruit])
```

For the first baskets, each fruit is followed by the next in `fruits` order, but as soon as one will be reused as `fruit1`, the corresponding `fruit2` will be the next. Absolutely no random here, but the distribution covers all possible case with equivalent *probability* (percentage of occurence)

Comment: That's actually pretty good.  I'd rather it 'appeared' a bit more random, but I think I can fudge this by mixing up the order of baskets within the list and then straightening it out again once the fruits have been allocated.

Comment: This is nice, when the number of baskets is increased there is a good and even distributions of fruits across all baskets. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is still not clear, this code will uniformly fill each basket with a random fruit. The weakness is that it necessarilly requires at least as many fruit choices as there are locations in baskets.

```
import numpy as np

for basket in baskets:
    for k in basket:
        if k!='basket':

            new_fruit = ''

            while new_fruit in list(basket.values()):
                new_fruit = np.random.choice(fruits)

            basket[k] = new_fruit
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't matter in which order the fruit slots are filled.  The problem I have with this code is that the fruit2 slot in baskets two, three, and four are empty.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. I suggest you edit your question to be more specific about your desired output as other users have already suggested.

Comment: @rafello I updated the answer to use random sampling. This way you do not need to mess with the list ordering.

Comment: This is great! I hadn't thought to use NumPy. Thanks for your patience.